# javascript connect to web site code not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my javascript code which ping Google for every 10 seconds and display the connection status to html MonitorInformation element. But when I click the html file to debug, the information displayed at MonitorInformation element is always "Connecting...wait". I have debugged for some time but can not figure out. Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="Monitor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Web Site Monitor</title>
</head>
<body  onload="setup()">
<div id="MonitorInformation">Connecting...wait</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Java script code:

```
function setup() {
    window.setInterval(PingWebSite, (10 * 1000));
}

function PingWebSite() {
    conObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    conObj.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", true);
    conObj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (conObj.readyState === 4) {
        if (conObj.status === 200) {    
                loading.innerText = "Service is available";             
            } else {
                MonitorInformation.innerText = "Service is not available";
            }
        } else {
            MonitorInformation.innerText = "Connecting to www.google.com ...";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: my fix using JSON

```
function setup() {
    window.setInterval(PingWebSite, (10 * 1000));
}

function PingWebSite() {

    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http_request.open("GET", "http://www.google.com", true);
    http_request.send(null);
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                MonitorInformation.innerText = "Connection ok";
                alert("ok");
            } else {
            MonitorInformation.innerText = "Connection fail";
            alert("fail");
            }
            http_request = null;
        }
    };
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="Monitor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Web Site Monitor</title>
</head>
<body  onload="setup()">
<div id="MonitorInformation">Connecting...wait</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: JSON won't work, you need to use JSONP, which only works if the service you are hitting provides it.

Comment: I am confused FlySwat, but my posted code in EDIT 1 section using JSON works. Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect to a site outside of your URL. Unless your code is on the google.com domain it won't work.

This is a browser security item called 'Same origin policy' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

If you want to do cross site calls like that you will have to use JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON as that lets you do that.

Comment: Thanks AutomatedTester, I have fixed this issue following your advice, could you review my fixed code please? (I have tested function works, but review from Guru like you is making myself more confident. :-) ) Please refers to EDIT 1 section of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cross domain XHR for which you don't have access to AFAIK.

Comment: I am surprised. I cannot use javascript code to get page from another site and mesh-up to my site?

Comment: Thanks soulscratch, I have fixed this issue by using JSON, could you review my fixed code please? (I have tested function works, but review from Guru like you is making myself more confident. :-) ) Please refers to EDIT 1 section of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a hidden iFrame to get around the cross domain limitations. A quick example to get you started:

(HTML Snippet)

```
<body>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <iframe id='hiddenFrame'></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function setup()
{
    var iFrame = document.getElementById('hiddenFrame');
    var changeEvent = function () 
    { 
        loading.innerText = "Service is Available";
    }
    // IE
    iFrame.onload = changeEvent;
    // Firefox
    iFrame.onreadystatechange = changeEvent;

    setInterval(PingWebSite, (10 * 1000));
}

function PingWebSite() {
    var iFrame = document.getElementById('hiddenFrame');
    iFrame.src = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: Thanks FlySwat! I am learning about cross site security policy from wiki pedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and I am confused about this statement -- "the policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties", I am confused about (1) running on pages means running javascript or other scripts on client side browser? (2) what means "each other's other's methods and properties"? I am accessing URL not access property like DIV's innerText property. Appreciate if you could clarify. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you forgot a semicolon there? E.g.: ...body  onload="setup();"...